# Got 414 Request-URI Too Large from Google when authenticating using Spring Security 3

Tags: openid, spring-security, google-openid

My steps are as follows:

1. the user goes to login page.
2. the user doesn't have an account, and goes for Google OpenId.
3. the user is prompted by Google login page, and enters login details.
4. the user gets Http 414.

414 Request-URI Too Large
The requested URL /accounts/SetSID... is too large to process.

A workaround is that the user must log in to Google before going to login page, then he won't be prompted by Google login page anymore.

The funny thing is that it was working yesterday.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hitting the max URI length of GET requests.
The solution is to send the request via POST. I guess you would have to do this specifically for google. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/google-federated-login-api/ldEUDr-2BGs.